# how to get the multiple of the principal value after dividing

Tags: php

I have a value of 12/4 and I want to get the value from multiples of 3 so that the result is an array of 3,6,9,12 how to make logic in php?

$a = (12 / 4);

i wan t get array(3,6,9,12)

Comment: are 12 and 4 are in separate variable ?

Comment: @NikleshRaut yes in a separate variable so that it will be divided according to the specified variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using a `FOR` loop as follows:

```
function myCalc($dividend, $divisor)
{
    $a = ($dividend/$divisor);
    $result = array();

    /** start a loop from the quotient which is $a
      * loop it until highest value i.e. $dividend is reached
      * increment each iteration by $a
     **/

    for($i=$a; $i<=$dividend; $i+=$a)
    {
        $result[] = $i;
    }

    return $result;
}

$result1 = myCalc(12, 4);
print_r($result1); // Array ( [0] => 3 [1] => 6 [2] => 9 [3] => 12 )

$result2 = myCalc(12, 6);
print_r($result2); // Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 4 [2] => 6 [3] => 8 [4] => 10 [5] => 12 )

$result3 = myCalc(55, 5);
print_r($result3); // Array ( [0] => 11 [1] => 22 [2] => 33 [3] => 44 [4] => 55 )
```

This will work for any numbers you need to calculate the multiplier array for.